# Wordpress Google Crawl Error

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler

I got a lot of 404 in Google Webmaster, and most of the problems are the link on my site that indexed by Google was added `.html` in the end of the url that's why it has a lot of 404 since my site using a permalinks that looks like `example.com/article/`

How to solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you see where those pages are being linked from?

Comment: it's linked from the actual page itself but it's added `.html` in the end of the url

Comment: If you open the page itself and look at the source, can you see where on that page is showing the .html?